# Where do the GSL league names 'Code S' and 'Code A' come from?

Tags: starcraft-2

The [Global Starcraft League](http://www.gomtv.net/) has subleagues called 'Code S' and 'Code A'.  Where did these names come from, and do the names have any special meaning?

Comment: Pretty sure "A" comes from iccup's rating system in brood war, from D -> A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because having a B-rank of players sounds bad.  A-rank (Code A) players are still  excellent, hardly deserving of a paltry, average, "B" grade, so they just shift up the top to something else: S.

As far as what they are, Code S is the big time league, while Code A has been likened to the minor leagues (though still quite an achievement)

More on this S thing from Giant Bomb's ["S-Rank" article](http://www.giantbomb.com/s-rank/92-2962/):

> ‘S-Rank’ is a term used in games, most commonly awarded at the end of stages with graded missions or side objectives.
>
> Originally created in Japan where anything below grade ‘C’ was considered a failure. The 'S-Rank'  [...] If the player is flawless or achieves perfection in something, it qualifies as an S.  Many people have wondered what the S stands for… Special? Super? No one knows for sure.

Comment: Yep and not to mention that some games even go as far as to grade em SS and SSS. Figured it ment Super.

Comment: There is a Code-B, too, though. -.-

Comment: @Decency It's not really called Code B, actually. The official name is "Up & Down Matches".

Comment: I wasn't referring to that. Code B in Korea refers to players who are allowed to enter into the qualification tournament for Code A, they have to be highly ranked on the Korean ladder (or be foreigners).